# How to set each bit in a byte array

Tags: c#, arrays

How do I set each bit in the following byte array which has 21 bytes or 168 bits to either zero or one?

```
byte[] logonHours
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, to clear every bit to zero you can just use [`Array.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear.aspx):

```
Array.Clear(logonHours, 0, logonHours.Length);
```

Setting each bit is *slightly* harder:

```
for (int i = 0; i < logonHours.Length; i++)
{
    logonHours[i] = 0xff;
}
```

If you find yourself filling an array often, you could write an extension method:

```
public static void FillArray<T>(this T[] array, T value)
{
    // TODO: Validation
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[BitArray.SetAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.setall.aspx):

```
System.Collections.BitArray a = new System.Collections.BitArray(logonHours);
a.SetAll(true);
```

Note that this copies the data from the byte array. It's not just a wrapper around it.

Answer (score 1):

This may be more than you need, but ...

Usually when dealing with individual bits in any data type, I define a const for each bit position, then use the binary operators |, &, and ^.

i.e.

```
    const byte bit1 = 1;
    const byte bit2 = 2;
    const byte bit3 = 4;
    const byte bit4 = 8;
                  .
                  .
    const byte bit8 = 128;
```

Then you can turn whatever bits you want on and off using the bit operations.

```
   byte byTest = 0;
   byTest = byTest | bit4;
```

would turn bit 4 on but leave the rest untouched.

You would use the & and ^ to turn them off or do more complex exercises.

Obviously, since you only want to turn all bits up or down then you can just set the byte to 0 or 255. That would turn them all off or on.